# How to check for dependencies conflict between toml files in poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

There are two packages a and b

```
├── a
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── a.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── poetry.lock
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── README.rst
├── b
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── b.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── poetry.lock
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── README.rst
```

I am trying to create a library from them but track if there is conflict(or different versions) between the dependencies in their respective poetry files. Is their easy way of doing that in poetry?